# Is the total volume proportional to the number of identical sound sources?

Tags: acoustics, volume, perception

1. What happens to the perception of loudness when 4 identical devices placed around the listener play a sound sample? Will they sound 4 times "louder" than 1 device?
2. What if they're a bit out of sync?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about human perception, not physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not. This is because the loudness response of the ear is *logarithmic*, which means to double the apparent loudness you must increase the acoustic power of the source not by a factor of two but by a factor of *ten*.

If you have one sound source and double its intensity by adding a second identical source next to it, you will barely be able to perceive the difference. If you double that so you have four sources, you'll easily be able to hear the difference- but it will not even be twice as loud. For that, you'd need *ten* sources.

NOTE: This assumes that each source is perfectly in phase with all the others.

Comment: Do you have citations to empirical studies?

Comment: Any college text on acoustics will. This is one of the fundamentals of loudness perception.

Comment: @greenback See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber–Fechner_law) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevens%27s_power_law) Wikipedia article.

Comment: “*logarithmic, which means to double the apparent loudness you must increase the acoustic power of the source not by a factor of two but by a factor of ten.*” - This is not what logarithmic means. Logarithmic in general means that to *add* to the result, you need to *multiply* the source. Not to change the multiplication factor from two to ten.

Comment: in this context, logarithmic refers to the sensitivity profile of the human ear, in which every doubling in perceived loudness requires a 10X increase in power.

Comment: Knowing that seems I should not expect that several smartphones synchronized via an app like AmpMe (allows to play music simultaneously) can produce sound as loud as a, say, average TV. Sad.